# How to compare html literal using c#

Tags: c#, html

I need to compare two HTMLs. 
One i get from a URL using the `webClient.DownloadString` method. Other i have on a bucket on the `Amazon S3`. The problem is that when i get using the `DownloadText` method of amazon sdk, the HTML special characters are substituted with the html codes like `&quot;` for double quotes. So the comparision is always different. I would like to know if theres a work around to deal with this problem.

If the file is not in the amazon but in my file system, the method `File.ReadText` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source is 'escaped' the HtmlDecode method should do the trick for you:

```
using System.Web;

string escapedSource = "&lt;p&gt;&quot;Some content to be unescaped&quot;&lt;/p&gt;";
string unescapedresult = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(escapedSource);
unescapedresult.Dump();
```

Result:

```
<p>"Some content to be unescaped"</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx

So for example:

```
var amazonTextEncoded = AmazonS3Client.DownloadText();
var amazonTextDecoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(amazonTextEncoded);

// Compare amazonTextDecoded to file content...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode the Html string and get rid of the html special characters.

I would use a diff tool such as DiffChecker. Google for it.